# Sharepoint 2013 Preview Pane View - Search not working

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, preview

I have a SharePoint Document library that's using the Preview Pane view.
As the preview Pane view looses the Document library Search functionality - Id'm trying to add this back in as a custom Control dynamically as per code below. However the Search control no longer fires or submits a request to search the document library. Is there a better way to achieve this functionality?
Thanks
Daz

```
$('<div id="searchSection>
<div id="inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ2" class="ms-InlineSearch-DivBaseline"><br/><br/><div id="inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ2_lsparent" class="ms-InlineSearch-Outline-Baseline ms-InlineSearch-Outline-Empty">*<input id="inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ2_lsinput" title="Type something and hit enter to search this library" class="ms-helperText ms-textSmall ms-InlineSearch-SearchBox-Baseline ms-InlineSearch-SearchBox-EmptyUnfocused" type="text" value="" maxlength="2048"><span id="inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ2_lsimgspan" class="ms-inlineSearch-searchImgSpanBase ms-inlineSearch-searchImgSpanStandard">*<img id="inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ2_lsimg" class="ms-inlineSearch-searchImg" src="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23" title="Search"></span></div><div id="inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ2_lsprogress" class="ms-InlineSearch-SearchProgress" style="visibility: hidden;"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/loadingcirclests16.gif" title="Searching..." style="vertical-align:middle;"></div></div>
</div>').after($('#idKeyFiltersHeader'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Enabling Search Box in Preview pane is not supported but at first, you can configure the Search Box Web Part then modify it by using Script Editor Web Part.

Here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/search/configure-properties-of-the-search-box-web-part?redirectedfrom=MSDN)